# Reference and Copyright figures and tables

Tags: tables, citing, copyright

How can I add a copyright and reference information to my figures and tables. I've structured it like this:

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=7cm]{price_regions.JPG}
\caption{random caption}
\label{fig:regions}
\end{figure}
And this:
\begin{tabular}{ |p{6cm}|p{1cm}|p{1cm}|p{1cm}|p{1cm}| p{1cm}| }
 \hline
 \multicolumn{6}{|c|}{Rand} \\
 \hline
 a & b* c & c & f & g & h\\
 \hline
 1  & Fair & High & Low & High & High\\
 2  & Fair & Low & Low & High & High\\
 3  & Low & Fair & Low & High & High\\
 4  & Fair & High & Low & Fair & Fair\\
 5  & Low & Fair & Low & High & Fair\\
 6  & Low & High & Low & High & Fair\\
 7  & Fair & High & Low & High & High\\
 8 & Low & Low & Low & Low & Low\\
 9 & Low & Low & Low & Fair & Fair\\
 \hline
 \multicolumn{6}{|c|}{*Note} \\
 \hline
\end{tabular}\\\\
```

Should I do something differently

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!  Where and how exactly would you like the copyright and reference information to be displayd? Would you mind adding a sketch of the expected output to your question?

Comment: it's just text you can place it after the tabular or graphic as a paragrah within thefigure or table environment

Comment: Anything that works is fine how would I do that?

Comment: Just type it in where you want it: e.g., `\par Copyright Erik\end{figure}` to put it in its own paragraph after the caption in the figure environment.